# Powershell - Using Where-object, find strings (emails addresses) with numbers

Tags: powershell, office365, where-clause

We are using Office 365 and came across an issue where duplicate accounts were created. This cause a numerical addition to the users address (john.doe@c0mpany.onmicrosoft.com would also be john.doe5826@c0mpany.onmicrosoft.com and a full seperate user).

```
Get-MsolUser -All | where {$_.proxyaddresses -like "smtp:*'$(\d)'@C0mpanyName.onmicrosoft.com"} | select userprincipalname, proxyaddresses,displayname
```

I've run out of ideas and this sample I've added was the best I could up with to search for a proxyaddress with numbers in the address.

I believe this would work if we didn't use a domain with numbers in it (note the 0 in C0mpany, but instead add 4 more numbers, so I can't use the {4} to dictate that it can only be 4 numbers that we are searching for).

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing wildcard and regex matching.

Try this:

```
Get-MsolUser -All | where {$_.proxyaddresses -match "smtp:.+\d@C0mpanyName\.onmicrosoft\.com"} | select userprincipalname, proxyaddresses,displayname
```

And see:

```
Get-Help about_Regular_Expressions
Get-Help about_Wildcards
```

Comment: You're the man, thank you! Today is the first time I've ran into this and you nailed it.  I'd give you a +1, but my reputation is too low :-/

Comment: If that solved your problem, can you mark it as the answer so the question doesn't hang around as "unaswered" forever?